# What is the Solution for this situation?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-modal

While changing another modal, "Modal-open" class is removed from the body and opened modal not scroll Y-axis properly?

Here is [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sangrai/ambxLyqo/)

Kindly suggest the solution?

CODE:

```
<html>
 <body>
<div class="wrapper">
        <!--=== Header v8 ===-->
        <div class="header-v8 header-sticky">
            <!-- Topbar blog -->
            <div class="blog-topbar gap-top-5s">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-4 clearfix">
                            <ul class="list-inline">
                                <li class="cd-log_reg home"><button class="cd-signin btn-primary" data-target="#login-modal" data-toggle="modal" role="button" href="#"><i class="fa fa-sign-in"></i> Sign in</button></li>
                                <li class="cd-log_reg"><button class="cd-signin btn-primary" data-target="#register-modal" data-toggle="modal" role="button" href="#"><i class="fa fa-sign-up"></i> Sign up</button></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div><!--/end row-->
                </div><!--/end container-->
            </div>
            <!-- End Topbar blog -->
        </div>
    </div>



<!-- MODAL-STARTS -->

<!-- BEGIN # MODAL LOGIN -->
<div class="modal fade" id="login-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content col-sm-12">
                <div class="modal-header" align="center">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    </button>
                </div>

                <!-- Begin # DIV Form -->
                <div id="div-forms">

                    <!-- Begin # Login Form -->
                    <form id="login-form">
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <center><h4 class="skyblue-txt bline-btm pad-btm-10">LOGIN</h4></center>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="skyblue-txt"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> Username</label>
                                <input id="login_username" class="form-control cst-control" placeholder="Username " required="" type="text">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="skyblue-txt"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i> Password</label>
                                <input id="login_password" class="form-control cst-control" placeholder="Password" required="" type="password">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="checkbox">
                                    <label class="skyblue-txt">
                                        <input type="checkbox"> Remember me
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <div class="form-groups">
                                <button class="btn btn-5 btn-primary"><span>Login</span></button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group text-center">
                                <a class="cd-signin lostform">Forget Password</a><br>
                                <span class="">New User</span> <a href="#" role="button" class="myloginpage1">Register Now</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                    <!-- End # Login Form -->



                </div>
                <!-- End # DIV Form -->

            </div>
        </div>
</div>
<div class="modal fade" id="register-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content col-sm-12">
                <div class="modal-header" align="center">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    </button>
                </div>

                <!-- Begin # DIV Form -->
                <div id="div-forms">
                <!-- Begin | Register Form -->
                    <form id="register-form">
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <center><h4 class="bline-btm pad-btm-10">REGISTER</h4></center>
                            <div id="div-register-msg">
                                <center><div id="icon-register-msg" class="fa fa-facebook"></div>
                                <a href="#"><span id="text-register-msg">Register with facebook</span></a></center>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input id="register_username" class="form-control cst-control" placeholder="Full Name" required="" type="text">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input id="register_email" class="form-control cst-control" placeholder="E-Mail" required="" type="text">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input id="password" class="form-control cst-control" placeholder="Password" required="" type="text">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input id="password" class="form-control cst-control" placeholder="Re-enter Password" required="" type="text">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <div>
                               <button class="btn btn-5 btn-primary"><span>Register</span></button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="last-btngroup">
                                <a class="cd-signin myloginpage" href="#">Log In</a>
                                <a class="lostform" href="#">Forget Password</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                    <!-- End | Register Form -->

                </div>
                <!-- End # DIV Form -->

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- END # MODAL LOGIN -->
<div class="modal fade" id="lost-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content col-sm-12">
                <div class="modal-header" align="center">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    </button>
                </div>

                <!-- Begin # DIV Form -->
                <div id="div-forms">
                <!-- Begin | Lost Password Form -->
                    <form id="lost-form">
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <div id="div-lost-msg">
                                <div id="icon-lost-msg" class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></div>
                                <span id="text-lost-msg">Type your e-mail.</span>
                            </div>
                            <input id="lost_email" class="form-control cst-control" placeholder="E-Mail" required="" type="text">
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <div>
                                <button class="btn btn-5 btn-primary"><span>Submit</span></button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="last-btngroup">
                                <a class="cd-signin myloginpage" href="#">Log In</a>
                                <a href="#" role="button" class="myloginpage1">Register</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                    <!-- End | Lost Password Form -->
                  </div>
                <!-- End # DIV Form -->

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </body></html>
```

CSS:

```
    .btn-primary {
  border: 2px solid #337ab7;
  border-radius: 3px;
  float: left;
  font-size: 18px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  min-width: 300px;
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  width: 100%;
  text-decoration:none;
}
/* SIGN-IN-MODAL */
/* MODAL-CSS */

#login-modal .modal-dialog {
    width: 350px;
}
#register-modal .modal-dialog {
    width: 350px;
}
#lost-modal .modal-dialog {
    width: 350px;
}


#div-login-msg, #div-lost-msg, #div-register-msg {
  border: 0 none;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 28px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  transition: all 500ms ease-in-out 0s;
}

#div-login-msg.success,
#div-lost-msg.success,
#div-register-msg.success {
    border: 1px solid #68c3a3;
    background-color: #c8f7c5;
}

#div-login-msg.error,
#div-lost-msg.error,
#div-register-msg.error {
    border: 1px solid #eb575b;
    background-color: #ffcad1;
}

#icon-login-msg, #icon-lost-msg, #icon-register-msg {
  background-color: #3b5998;
  color: #fff;
  float: left;
  line-height: 28px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 500ms ease-in-out 0s;
  width: 30px;
}

#icon-login-msg.success,
#icon-lost-msg.success,
#icon-register-msg.success {
    background-color: #68c3a3 !important;
}

#icon-login-msg.error,
#icon-lost-msg.error,
#icon-register-msg.error {
    background-color: #eb575b !important;
}

#img_logo {
    max-height: 100px;
    max-width: 100px;
}

/* #########################################
   #    override the bootstrap configs     #
   ######################################### */

.modal-backdrop.in {
    filter: alpha(opacity=50);
    opacity: .8;
}

.modal-content {
    background-color: #ececec;
    border: 1px solid #bdc3c7;
    border-radius: 0px;
    outline: 0;
}

.modal-header {
    min-height: 16.43px;
    padding: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
    border-bottom: 0px;
}

.modal-body {
    position: relative;
    padding: 5px 15px 5px 15px;
}

.modal-footer {
    padding: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
    text-align: left;
    border-top: 0px;
}

.checkbox {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.btn {
    border-radius: 0px;
}

.btn:focus,
.btn:active:focus,
.btn.active:focus,
.btn.focus,
.btn:active.focus,
.btn.active.focus {
    outline: none;
}

.btn-lg, .btn-group-lg>.btn {
    border-radius: 0px;
}

.btn-link {
    color: #95a5a6;
}

.btn-link:hover, .btn-link:focus {
    color: #2c3e50;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.glyphicon {
    top: 0px;
}

.form-control {
  border-radius: 0px;
}
#div-login-msg > span {
  font-size: 12px;
}
.pad-btm-10{padding-bottom:10px;}
#login-form label{font-weight:100; font-family:Montserrat; }
#login-modal, #register-modal, #lost-modal{background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)}
#login-modal .modal-dialog {
  max-width: 380px;
  width: 100%;
  top:10%;
}
#register-form .form-control::-moz-placeholder {
  color: #999;
  opacity: 1;
}

.vfy-btn {
  float: left;
  font-size: 11px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding: 2px 25px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background:#0097d0; color:#fff;
}
.vfy-btn :hover{color:#fff;}
.cd-signin.lostform {
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  width: 100%;
  color:#0dbc42;
}
.myloginpage1{color:#0dbc42;}

.last-btngroup{
    margin-top:10px;
    color:#0dbc42;
}
.last-btngroup a{color:#0dbc42;}
.last-btngroup a:first-child{margin-right:15px;}

/* 
INDIVIDUAL-CAT */
/*  bhoechie tab */
div.bhoechie-tab-container{
  z-index: 10;
  position: fixed;
  right:0;
  top:15px;
  padding: 0 !important;
  margin: 0px;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  opacity: 0.97;
  filter: alpha(opacity=97);
}
div.bhoechie-tab-menu{
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
}
div.bhoechie-tab-menu div.list-group{
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
div.bhoechie-tab-menu div.list-group>a{
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
div.bhoechie-tab-menu div.list-group>a .glyphicon,
div.bhoechie-tab-menu div.list-group>a .fa {
  color: #5A55A3;
}
div.bhoechie-tab-menu div.list-group>a:first-child{
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
  -moz-border-top-right-radius: 0;
}
div.bhoechie-tab-menu div.list-group>a:last-child{
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
  -moz-border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
}
div.bhoechie-tab-menu div.list-group>a.active,
div.bhoechie-tab-menu div.list-group>a.active .glyphicon,
div.bhoechie-tab-menu div.list-group>a.active .fa{
  background-color: #5A55A3;
  background-image: #5A55A3;
  color: #ffffff;
}
div.bhoechie-tab-menu div.list-group>a.active:after{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  right: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -13px;
  border-bottom: 13px solid transparent;
  border-top: 13px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid #5A55A3;
}

div.bhoechie-tab-content{
  background-color: #ffffff;
  /* border: 1px solid #eeeeee; */
  /*padding-left: 20px;*/
  padding-top: 10px;
}

div.bhoechie-tab>div.bhoechie-tab-content:not(.active) {
    display:none;
}
.gap-top-5s{margin-top:7%;}
```

JS:

```
   $(".myloginpage").click(function(){
    $('#lost-modal').modal('hide');
    $('#register-modal').modal('hide');
    $("#login-modal").modal('show');
 });
   $(".myloginpage1").click(function(){
    $('#lost-modal').modal('hide');
    $('#login-modal').modal('hide');
    $("#register-modal").modal('show');
 });

   $(".lostform").click(function(){
    $('#register-modal').modal('hide');
    $('#login-modal').modal('hide');
    $("#lost-modal").modal('show');
 });
```

Comment: Seems to work fine to me. Can you please explain your problem with more details?

Comment: I have another page with some more content used same process. While click on one of the button a modal-open class is add on the body and thw whole page is overflowed hidden. The backpage page sliding is stopped due to this class but when you click on register the while opened modal of login the opened modal class from the body is removed and the page is scroll down. I want to scroll modal active part not the inactive of back body part.

Comment: Please come up with a useful question title that hints at the gist of the question.

Answer (score 0):

It can help you.

```
$(document)
    .on('shown.bs.modal', '.modal', function () {
    $(document.body).addClass('modal-open')
});
```

Working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ambxLyqo/5/)

Comment: Make click event on close button and remove class `modal-open` from body.

Comment: Can you add the function on the above function you have written?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('hidden.bs.modal', '.modal', function() {
    $(document.body).addClass('modal-open')
});
```

Comment: @khushi  While click on close button "modal-open" class should be removed

Comment: you got your answer?